# Jquery save changes only when click Save button

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have this Jquery code

```
            $('.btn.btn-primary.addcaregiver').click(function (b) {
                var $thiscaregiver = $(b.target),
                    $tr = $thiscaregiver.closest("tr");
                var caregiverid = $tr.find(".cgcid").eq(0).val();
                $.post("/Companies/Associate", { patientId: cid, caregiverId: caregiverid });

            });
            $('.btn.btn-default.btn_delete.removecaregiver').click(function (b) {
                var $thiscaregiver = $(b.target),
                    $tr = $thiscaregiver.closest("tr");
                var caregiverid = $tr.find(".cgcid").eq(0).val();
                $.post("/Companies/AssociateRemove", { patientId: cid, caregiverId: caregiverid });
```

Now It send data to the backend immediately by click('.btn.btn-primary.addcaregiver and btn.btn-default.btn_delete.removecaregiver) , but I need to do this only when click Save button - for this two - .btn.btn-primary.addcaregiver and btn.btn-default.btn_delete.removecaregiver  . If we click Save button -then all changes(all .addcaregiver and all .removecaregiver)  go to the backend. If we do not click on Save button all changes do not go to the backend. How can I do this?

Comment: Add `e.preventDefault()` after `function (e) {`

Comment: For what I must do this?

Comment: Because all buttons (`<button>` tags) inside a form submit data when they are clicked. So you have to add `e.preventDefault` to all of them in their respective `click` handlers. It avoids submitting the form by "preventing the default" behavior (which I described inthe first phrase).

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ is correct! Another solution is to go to the button html element and override type attribute: `type="button"`

Comment: Thank u. But my question was How To add to my code button Save and Save changes only when click this button.